# How to handle the Facebook In-App Browser on my Site?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, facebook

My site is having issues "calculating/determining" the browser window of the Facebook In-App browser. I have noticed that the top menu/search bar (blue bar) takes up X number of pixels, while the tool bar at the bottom (grey bar) takes Y pixels.

Just by usability, the top of the web browser seems to respect the bottom of the blue bar however does not seem to respect the bottom grey bar. It almost appears that the bottom grey bar is an overlay. So it just seems like the browser frame extends below the iPhone's screen and under the grey bar. Has anyone seen similar issues?

After all that, I have several elements on my site which are absolutely positioned to the bottom of the window however that means that they extend off the iPhone's physical screen or it displays below this grey bar. Has anyone determined a proper way of handling this?

If a user is using iOS 10, then it seems like Facebook allows you to scroll the window, but on iOS 9 then it seems like Facebook does not allow you to scroll to hide the blue & grey bars.

Comment: Has been Answered here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421247/wrong-viewport-page-height-in-embedded-facebook-browser-in-ios-9-x